# Theme My Login Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress

Perhaps this question is best answered by someone who has used the plugin.

The problem is that the 'Forgot Password' link doesn't work in the login page.

The plugin generates a list of pages, `website.com/login/` for a login page. On this page, however, when I enter incorrect details it show an error message and 'Forgot password' link. This link is: `website.com/login/?action=lostpassword`

Now what it should do is: reload the page, and display the lost password form on the `/login/` page, however it doesn't.

A simple fix would be to create a custom Lost Password page and 301 redirect the above link.

The funny thing is that it works fine on other sites, but not this one (Same plugins, same setup, just doesn't work - I know this is impossible)

Comment: You may need to re-run “Permalinks” to sometimes get the pages on Theme My Login to work.

Comment: @CKG thanks, but what do you mean by re-run?  Simply save the settings in the permalinks section again?

Comment: Go to `Settings > Permalinks` in the backend here  first choose  `Plain` and save. Again change to new that you want..see here https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-permalinks/